# angularjs service not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

I have this service:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').factory('GroupService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var groups = [];

    return{
        list: function () {
            return groups;
        },
        retrieve: function () {
            $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "/enterprises/_groups"
            }).success(function (response) {
                groups = response;
            }).error(function () {
                console.log("failed")
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

and this is my controller:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').controller('GroupsController', function($scope, $http, GroupService) {
    GroupService.retrieve();
    $scope.items = GroupService.list();
});
```

So, in my controller, I am first getting the result from the API so that the variable groups(in the service) gets assigned, then I am using the list() method to assign the values to $scope.items.

I am sure that API is returning results. But the

```
groups = response
```

part is not working correctly. When I changed it to

```
groups.push(response)
```

it is working but the result is a list inside a list, which I dont't want: [[ Object, Object, Object ]]

I want this: [ Object, Object, Object ]

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason

```
groups = response
```

is not working is because you're sending an async request that will replace the groups reference after you've already retrieved the old reference via the `list` function. The reason it works with the `push` modification is because Angular creates a watch that notices that the collection has changed and updates your view. However, your code is now working, but you don't understand why it works, and it's prone to breaking unexpectedly.

When dealing with asynchronous code, the best way to deal with it is to write your own code to take that into account. Here's a version that does the whole thing in an async fashion:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').factory('GroupService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    var groupsResult;

    return{
        retrieve: function () {
            if (groupsResult) { return groupsResult; }
            return groupsResult = $http({
                method: "get",
                url: "/enterprises/_groups"
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function () {
                console.log("failed")
            });
        }
    }
}]);

angular.module('autotestApp').controller('GroupsController', 
    ['$scope', 'GroupService', function($scope, GroupService) {
        GroupService.retrieve().then(function (groups) {
            $scope.items = groups;
        });
    }]);
```

Comment: this is working :) but I need that groups variable to be assigned to response.data so that I could use it in another controller. However, I did not mention that in my question and you answer is correct, so I will accept it

Comment: I edited the answer to add caching of the response, so you can use the result in different controllers but it only makes the single request.

Answer (score 1):

One of the fixes you could use is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
     groups.push(response[i]);
});
```

That way you would have `[ Object, Object, Object ]`

**EDIT:**

One thing you could try is the following, change your retrieve function to return your promise:

```
  return{
            list: function () {
                return groups;
            },
            retrieve: function () {
                var promise = $http({
                    method: "get",
                    url: "/enterprises/_groups"
                }).success(function (response) {
                    groups = response;
                }).error(function () {
                    console.log("failed")
                });

                return promise;
            }
        }
```

and then in your controller:

```
angular.module('autotestApp').controller('GroupsController', function($scope, $http, GroupService) {
    GroupService.retrieve().finally(function () {
         $scope.items = GroupService.list();
    });
});
```

I think your `groups = response` is working, but when you do `$scope.items = GroupService.list()` the request isn't finished yet.

Comment: yeah you are right but when I have thousands of results coming from api, would it not be expensive?)

Comment: It would be better, in terms of performance, to manually iterate through your list instead of using `angular.forEach`. `for (var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; ++i) {}` (http://jsperf.com/angular-foreach-vs-native-for-loop)

Comment: @MichelTomé your edit is almost identical to what I was writing. :)

Comment: @GeoffreyB, i edited my answer, thanks for reminding me. *slaps self*

Comment: @Rytmis Sorry for that :P

Answer (score 0):

do `groups.concat(response)`
this will flatten the items & add it to parent list rather than appending a single element.

Comment: not working, I think it is because concat works only with primitive types. Here I am getting objects

Comment: run on Node REPL:::::a = ['b','c','d']
[ 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
b = [Object(), Object(), Object()]
[ {}, {}, {} ]
> a.concat(b)
[ 'b', 'c', 'd', {}, {}, {} ]